# Container can't find bind mounted files

Tags: docker

When I run this docker command like this, I get errors:

```
$ docker run -v $PWD:/tmp bobrik/curator --config /tmp/testconfig.yml /tmp/actions-daily.yml

Usage: curator [OPTIONS] ACTION_FILE

Error: Invalid value for "--config": Path "/tmp/testconfig.yml" does not exist.
```

For some reason, Docker cannot find this file path, even though that file exists in that directory and its permission is set to 775.   Furthermore, when I inspect that container, I can see this Mount information:

```
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": [
            "/cygdrive/c/myUbuntu18/rootfs/home/jdepaul/repos/curator/test/utils:/tmp"
        ],
```

and this further down:

```
    "Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/cygdrive/c/myUbuntu18/rootfs/home/jdepaul/repos/curator/test/utils",
            "Destination": "/tmp",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        }
    ],
```

Comment: That looks like a Cygwin-specific path that the Docker-native tools won't understand.

Comment: I thought that too.... so I ran the same command in Windows Docker, I adjusted the paths to be Windows paths and I got the same error message...

Comment: I ran it again on Windows, and this time it worked.   Closing

Answer (score 0):

Run it on Windows, like this:

```
docker run -v C:\Users\ja006652\cure:/tmp bobrik/curator --config /tmp/testconfig.yml /tmp/daily-dev-action.yml --dry-run
```